# GWT, GXT HtmlEditor, Key Event

Tags: gwt, gxt, html-editor

No matter what I try, when I add 
        addListener(Events.KeyPress, new Listener() {
            public void handleEvent(FieldEvent e) {
                changed = true;
            }
        });

OR

```
    addKeyListener(new KeyListener() {
        public void componentKeyDown(ComponentEvent event) {
            changed = true;
        }
    });
```

Nothing registers... the event is not captured. Anybody know how to make this work?

Thank you.
Kirt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently you have to extend `HtmlEditor` and overwrite `onEditorKeyDown()`.

```
class ExtendedHtmlEditor extends HtmlEditor {

    public ExtendedHtmlEditor() {
        super();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onEditorKeyDown(KeyDownEvent e) {
        super.onEditorKeyDown(e);
        Window.alert("w000t");
    }

}
```

See also [here](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?107468-HtmlEditor-KeyPress-event&highlight=htmleditor+onkeypress).

Comment: Yes, that works for me too... but my question says nothing about a standard GWT TextArea, does it?

Comment: Well, I have since found that GXT HtmlEditor does not implement any event handlers, so I have to extend that class and implement my own. Does anybody have a link or sample code for implements KeyDownHandler?   Thank you.